# Split a string using an integer as a delimeter

Tags: python, regex

I have a rather long txt file filled with strings of the format `{letter}{number}{letter}`. For instance, the first few lines of my file are:

```
A123E
G234W
R3L
H4562T
```

I am having difficulty finding the correct `regex` pattern to separate each line by alpha and numeric.

For instance, in the first line, I would like an array with the results:

```
print first_line[0] // A
print first_line[1] // 123
ptin first_line[2] // E
```

It seems like `regex` would be the way to go, but I'm still a `regex` novice. Could someone help point me in the correct direction on how to do this?

Then I plan to iterate over each of the lines and use the info as necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Split on `\d+`:

```
import re
re.split(r'(\d+)', line)
```

`\d` is the character class matching the digits 0 through to 9, and we want to match at least 1 of them. By putting a capturing group around the `\d+`, [`re.split()` will include the match in the output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in *pattern*, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)', 'A123E')
['A', '123', 'E']
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on *why* `(\d+)` works when `\d+` doesn't.

Comment: @mgilson: poko poko.. :-) Contrary to popular belief, my answers do not spring from my keyboard wholly formed in one fraction of a second!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split "If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list."

Comment: Wow...super simple! Thanks!

Comment: poko poko?  I'm not catching the reference ... In any event though, I didn't  realize that including capturing groups would cause `re.split` to keep the "delimiter".  Very useful.  I was trying to think of some overly clever way to use lookahead and lookbehind to get it to match ... It would have been a nightmare.  I'm glad you beat me to it :)

Comment: @mgilson: Sorry, Dutch colonial reference I fear, and I prolly misspelled it. It means: patience! It's origins are Indonesian, IIRC.